# Need to remove border to column header ag-grid react

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm getting a weird white border line for header check box selection in ag-grid react. Could you please help me get rid of this?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Below is my column definition:

```
 columnDefs: [
      {
        minWidth: 45,
        maxWidth: 45,
        headerCheckboxSelection: true,
        checkboxSelection: true,
        lockPosition: true,
        pinned: 'left',
        cellStyle: { border: 'none' }
      },
```

ag-grid-react version: 25.1.0

Thanks in advance!